# Replace div id on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Javascript:

```
$('nav').before('<div id="box">Open</div>');
$('#box').append('<div class="line"></div>');

$('#box').click(function(event) 
{
    $('nav').animate({height:'toggle'},200);
}
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    background: white;
    border: green;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

I want to make the box background color changed to yellow when box is clicked. How to add this css into it.

```
#box {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: Rather than change the id, you can use addClass() and add a class dictating the bg color. You can also use removeClass, or toggleClass() that will add/remove it with each click, which might be something you want.

Comment: hi @cfqueryparam could we have remove class and add new one?

Comment: @ayah See [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/). Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Do it using `.css()` in jQuery:

```
$('#box').click(function(event) 
{
  $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
  $('nav').animate({height:'toggle'},200);  
}
```

[Learn about .css() in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

---

**Solution 2:**

You can also do it using `.addClass()` in jQuery and some CSS:

```
$('#box').click(function(event) 
{
  $(this).addClass('yellowify');
  $('nav').animate({height:'toggle'},200);  
}
```

CSS:

```
.yellowify{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Learn about .addClass() in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: I go for solution 1. Ty mister.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try css pseudo, without script

```css
#box {
  background: white;
  /* updated */
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 7px;
  /* added */
  display: inline-block;
  /* added */
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* on click */

#box:active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Open</div>
```